# WebRequest ConsoleApplication issue

Tags: c#, webrequest

```
url = @"http://website"; 
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url); 
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; 
//request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("id", "pw","domain"); 
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

```
 it works well in c# WindowsFormsApplication 
 but get 404 response in ConsoleApplication 
 ( web.config of website  )
```

Does any one know how to solve it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What are credentials in console application? Are they same as in web application?

Comment: Do you have the same configuration in the app.config that you have in the web.config?

Comment: 404 is a status returned by a website indicating the resource could not be found - are you _absolutely sure_ the `url` is equal in both cases? Try use fiddler or another tool to diagnose the network traffic.